How do I show the website (.php using XAMPP) for my team using Live Share in VSCode?
I am using Visual Studio Code Live Share extension to collaborate with my team on a website project for our school. All I want is for my team to access the websites we've created. And in this case, I can't use Go Live on PHP files, like I can do with HTML normally. Sorry we're quite new to this collab stuff. What do I do or what do you guys recommend?
I am expecting for the site to update in real time as my friend and I make changes in Visual Studio Code-- the changes will be reflected when they refresh the browser page.

"the site to update in real-time" .... "the changes will be reflected when they refresh the browser page". These are two different objectives. The first one isn't supported by Apache (which is the webserver you get when you install XAMPP). The second one is its default behaviour. Which one do you actually want? The second one should already be working for you, as far as I know, unless there is something about your setup that you haven't fully explained in your post.

@ADyson Sorry for the vague question before. The thing is I can view my website locally through localhost on XAMPP, but my friend does not have immediate access to see it. Currently, he has to download the entire project folder and host it on his own XAMPP server each time I make a change, which is inefficient.
Is there a way to share my localhost server with him so that he can view the website every save without needing to set it up on his own every time? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Have you had a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/liveshare/use/share-server-visual-studio-code ?

This has nothing to do with visual-studio or stuff like that. This question is about how publishing web sites work. If you want your friend to access your local setup then you need to 1. open your local firewall, 2. take care for network resolution, for example by using a DynDNS provider and 3. give him the URL to your server.

I would recommend against that, though. Instead I would recommend to follow the standard setup, especially since this is an education project. Use git, probably with github as an exchange relay, a shared repository. Publish your changes once you think you have some small work finished on the project, push it to the shared repository. Then all your friend needs to do is pull those changes to his local setup. The advantage: you can both make local experiments (different ones at the same time) and exchange your attempts. That is how collaborative programming is done today.

@arkascha in respect of your first comment, the LiveShare feature takes some of the pain out of that, according to the documentation I provided. I don't disagree with your second point though

Sorry for the late reply, fellas! I've taken a look before at the link you sent in the @ADyson. Live Share does feature a live server to connect my local Apache server with in XAMPP (Stupid of me to not look at the guide). My team and I, I think, are already halfway done with our project. I now have the time to thank you guys for the support!

@arkascha Thanks for the tip! I am currently looking onto that since that is exactly the setup I'm looking for. I was honestly considering that awhile back. Hope I can stuff all this knowledge in my head tho. xD Any additional help or follow-to rules (especially privacy) regarding using all these will be greatly appreciated!

Taking all those different aspects together is a complete setup. Nothing you will find a single documentation or tutorial for. You will have to combine different solutions and you will also have to adapt those to your specific needs. I would recommend that you seek direct communication about specific questions you fail to answer yourself. My experience is that this is the best way to learn, especially if you can exchange yourself with people who have experience in the single topics.
